# Notepadd++ REGEX mark 1 line up and 1 line down

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have hundreds long text file with information containing on it as below:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting
remaining essentially unchanged
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested
Six Dragon is at Platinum Cineplex Singapore.
July 6, 2017 Singapore
more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum ... 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
Six Dragon
July 27 at 8:53 AM
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
```

The line is very long (almost 1000 lines).

I want to copy to clipboard/mark all information that line containing:

```
Six Dragon is at Platinum Cineplex Singapore.
July 6, 2017 Singapore
more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum ...
```

and

```
Six Dragon
July 27 at 8:53 AM
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
```

or in other option, i want to mark all text 1 line before date and 1 line after date

**/*
Here is my progress this far:
*/**

June 15

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}(^[a-zA-Z]+ \d{1,2}\r)[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}
```

January 12, 2017

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}(^[a-zA-Z]+ \d{1,2}, \d{1,4})[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}
```

June 27 at 31:26

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}(^[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2} at \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}
```

May 27 Singapore

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}(^[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2} [a-zA-Z]+\r)[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}
```

How to **copy - paste** those results to clipboard, and how to do some looping for other files?

Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please share your progress on the regex so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this:

`.*\r?\n[JFMASOND]\w+\h*\d{1,2}\h*(?:,?\h*(?:\d{4})?\h+\w+|at\h*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\h*(?:\h+AM|\h+PM:)?)?\h*\r?\n.*`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qi7bHb/3/)**

If you want to delete all content excepted those lines, use this instead:

`([^\n]*\r?\n[JFMASOND]\w+\h*\d{1,2}\h*(?:,?\h*(?:\d{4})?\h+\w+|at\h*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\h*(?:\h+AM|\h+PM:)?)?\h*\r?\n.*)|[^\n]*`

Replace by: `$1`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qi7bHb/5/)**

Comment: My problem now is how to copy all the result. I try to bookmark line but it only marking the first line of each result. so i cant copy 3 line result.

Comment: I added that option for you

Comment: Thanks @julio ... it does what i want